# Is there a script to show the added fields in response in Postman when using "additionalProperties": false?

Tags: automated-tests, postman

i have added `"additionalProperties": false` to schema scripts in postman. The `"additionalProperties": false,` worked fine and im getting error message when new fields are newly added to the json response and not covered by schema. But is there a script to specify what fields are added in the json?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you cannot.

I have tried using itv4 directly instead of using it through pm...

like below... The best I have obtained is the number of fields that are exceeding... but not the name.

```
const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "code": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
};

console.log(tv4.validate(body, schema))
console.log(tv4.validateResult(body, schema))
console.log(tv4.validateMultiple(body, schema));
```

Comment: @[Nisrine Bou Ghannam] Was my answer useful? @Nis

Comment: in my issue im validating the schema to the json response 
so I need to access the json response attributes and compare it to the schema
@[Jose Marin]

Comment: but i also tried to add JSON instead of body in the validation but it printed the same error message I'm getting from  `pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 pm.test("Explicitly ", function () {
    let Ajv = require('ajv');
    let ajv = Ajv()
    let result = ajv.validate(schema, jsonData);
    pm.expect(result, JSON.stringify(ajv.errors)).to.be.true;
});
```

this will show the additional property there is a bug for this already :

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9276